# From bad high school grades to becoming a professor in mathematics

Tags: career-path, grades

I know it is possible, but are there professors (kept anonymous) who did poorly in high school?

Comment: Why do you want to know? This is only marginally on topic (if that) here.

Comment: I don't believe listing individuals is appropriate here (certainly not as an answer to the question "Who had bad high school grades?"

Comment: I know several stories, but they are not mine to share. I had multiple professors in grad school who were poor high school students. This includes two professors who were high school dropouts and another who skipped >180d days their junior year of high school before deciding they wanted to go to high school.

Comment: This question could use some improvement.  I mean, right now, the obvious correct answer is just "Yes."  It's also largely unhelpful.  The thing that you're asking is not actually the thing you want/need to know.  I suspect that you'd be better served with something like "starting from bad grades in math, what would be necessary to become a successful math professor" and possibly some further details about current conditions.

Comment: I'll note that if you are the high school student with bad grades, knowing an answer to this isn't going to help you. Only your own efforts will. It is possible  to do better as many have. People don't start out knowing everything and it takes work to succeed. Do that work.

Comment: I am reminded of the video of the chemistry Nobel prize winner who mentioned in his speech that he got an F in chemistry at some point